# How to use the value in PSLinkListCell in preference bundle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cydia, tweak, theos

I would like to make a preference bundle for my jailbreak tweak.
I successfully made a preference bundle with a switch that works.

But I would like a setting to choose color. 
Example:

```
         Blue      
Color >  Yellow       
         Green
```

So if I click on **Color**, it would bring me to another screen which ask me to choose either "**Blue**", "**Yellow**" or "**Green**"
I have looked at tutorials on the net, and I think this is a `PSLinkList`.

But I want my tweak to read the plist and record what color is chosen.
I think it would read the `validValues` of the `PSLinkList`, am I right?

But what code would I use to read the plist?

**EDIT**: Nate helped me with adding the PSListcontroller but I met one problem:

[image]

Here is my plist
http://pastebin.com/uNKzLBrf

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>items</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>cell</key>
      <string>PSGroupCell</string>
      <key>label</key>
      <string>Main</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>cell</key>
      <string>PSSwitchCell</string>
      <key>default</key>
      <true/>
      <key>defaults</key>
      <string>com.junyi00.prefs</string>
      <key>key</key>
      <string>enabled</string>
      <key>label</key>
      <string>Enable</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>cell</key>
      <string>PSGroupCell</string>
      <key>label</key>
      <string>Colors</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>cell</key>
      <string>PSListLinkCell</string>
      <key>defaults</key>
      <string>com.junyi00.prefs</string>
      <key>detail</key>
      <string>PSListItemsController</string>
      <key>key</key>
      <string>color</string>
      <key>label</key>
      <string>Color</string>
      <key>validTitles</key>
      <array>
        <string>Default</string>
        <string>Random</string>
        <string>Yellow</string>
        <string>Blue</string>
        <string>Red</string>
        <string>Green</string>
      </array>
      <key>validValues</key>
      <array>
        <string>Default</string>
        <string>Random</string>
        <string>Yellow</string>
        <string>Blue</string>
        <string>Red</string>
        <string>Green</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
  <key>title</key>
  <string>Flash Color</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look [at this older tutorial](http://modmyi.com/forums/file-mods/22453-how-make-custom-menus-preferences-app-custom-preferences.html).  (*Note: for others reading this, the tutorial does not use [PreferenceLoader](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/PreferenceLoader), which should now be used for this task*)

In your case, I think the `MyAppName.plist` should contain something like this:

```xml
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>cell</key>
            <string>PSLinkListCell</string>
            <key>defaults</key>
            <string>com.mycompany.MyAppName</string>
            <key>detail</key>
            <string>PSListItemsController</string>
            <key>key</key>
            <string>color_pref</string>
            <key>label</key>
            <string>Color</string>
            <key>validTitles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Blue</string>
                <string>Yellow</string>
                <string>Green</string>
            </array>
            <key>validValues</key>
            <array>
                <string>Blue</string>
                <string>Yellow</string>
                <string>Green</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Which could then be read in by your code like this:

```objc
#define PLIST_FILENAME @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.mycompany.MyAppName.plist"
#define COLOR_PREF @"color_pref"

// an ivar
NSMutableDictionary* preferences;

- (void) initializePreferences {
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // initialize the preferences
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: PLIST_FILENAME]) {

        // make sure the user settings have default values assigned
        NSDictionary* defaultPrefs = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"Yellow", COLOR_PREF,
                                       nil];

        preferences = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: defaultPrefs];
        [preferences writeToFile: PLIST_FILENAME atomically: YES];
    } else {
        preferences = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: PLIST_FILENAME];
    }
}

- (NSString*) colorPref {
    return [preferences valueForKey: COLOR_PREF];
}
```

I've skipped over some steps here, as it sounds like you're familiar with [the general process of adding your jailbreak app, or tweak's, settings to Preferences.app](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/PreferenceLoader).  If this doesn't work for you, post a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this soon. I saw that tut before but mainly what i was trying was to read the plist with my own code but failed.

Comment: I finally fixed my problem after a few tries using this, but Awkwardly, I am not able to choose what color(only the cell is showing, clicking it does nothing)Please help here

Comment: I added the plist in the Top Post

Comment: @junyi00, you misspelled `PSLinkListCell`.  You typed `PSListLinkCell`.  That's the problem.