# Settings Bundle Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sdk

The following is my one of the items in my settings bundle. It is a simple linked list that allows users to choose a different note color for my application.

[image]

So far, I am retrieving the object through the key "noteColor." This will eventually allow me to determine which value was selected in my linked list.

```
NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/NCNotes.plist";
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

noteColor = [[dict objectForKey:@"noteColor"] intValue];
```

One thing I'm unsure about so far is if noteColor should be an integer or not. I'm assuming so, because I am using numbers for my values.

Assuming this is correct, I then try to switch the color of my note depending on the value that was selected (using cases). This doesn't seem to work.

```
switch (noteColor) {
    case 0:
        // Black
        noteView.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        break;
    case 1:
        // Blue
        noteView.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        break;

}
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: From what I see, `objectForKey:@"noteColor"` should return nil. You don't have a key named "noteColor". You have a key named "key" which value is "noteColor".

Comment: @Larme so I should use valueForKey?

Comment: Maybe this will help [How to use the value in PSLinkListCell in preference bundle?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318528/how-to-use-the-value-in-pslinklistcell-in-preference-bundle

Answer (score 0):

you won't be able to read it as noteColor using the method you show.. there is no key noteColor.
**That plist you show is meant to be used by the setting app to GENERATE default you read later on.**

also: noteColor is one-based according to above list